# How to list the data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to `render list` in `react js`.

Here is my code:

```
class First extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){ super(props); }

    render() {
        const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}];
        const listItems = data.map((d) => <li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>;

        return (
            <div>
                hello
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your map function in the return method of your Component , in your example you're initiating the value but you're not rendering anything in the DOM
 : [Here is a sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/644790rzxw)

```
class First extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){ super(props); }

    render() {
        const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}];    
        return (
            <div>
          {
               data.map((d) =>{
               return <li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>
              }) 
           }
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of how to render a list:

```
 class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    return (
      <ul>
        {data.map(item => {
          return <li>{item}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Example on CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/j3y3q9pwr3

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

I recommend splitting this into its own component.

```
// This is what's called a Functional Component
const DataList = ({
  ...props
}) => (
  <ol>
    props.map((d, index) => {
      return <li key={d.name + "-" + index}>{d.name}</li>;
    }
  </ol>
);

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.setState = {
      data: [{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DataList {...this.state.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is more of the "React way" to do this. It makes the parent's render method much cleaner/easier to read and allows you to extend this simple list (say you wanted to add a header or render the list in multiple places).

I know this was a simple example, but just want to mention it's best not to create variables for lists you will iterate over in your render method. The reason is that every time the parent gets rendered, it must allocate memory for the variables `data` and `listItems`. This is why I put them under state in `Parent`'s `constructor` method. It will only allocate this one time, for each instance of `Parent`.

Furthermore, this is more performant because the DataList component will only be instantiated once and React can perform it's diffing algorithms on the list without having to recreate the whole thing each time. If this got bigger, you could start adding functionality around conditional rendering of the list based on if data exists or add life cycle methods to only render the list if data changed (though to add life cycle methods you'd need to change this from a functional component to a class based one).

I hope this helps.